# Opaque bricks with no center post?

Tags: piece-information

What is the purpose of 1x2 red bricks without a post inside the brick? I know they often leave out the middle post on transparent bricks to make them look more window-like, but what about in opaque pieces? I have a few from bricks of this type that are probably from sets from the 70s/80s but I'm not sure what sets they came from, let alone what clever things you can do with them that you can't do with a regular brick of the same size.

Answer (score 5):

I'd wager it was mostly to save plastic. Many of the 1x family of bricks used to come with far fewer posts inside, like so: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=crssprt02 but notice they quit making that style in 1969.

Answer (score 3):

A comment on [this thread](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/95/how-has-the-basic-brick-changed-over-the-years) got me headed in the right direction of research. Before 1958, *none* of the bricks had tubes inside, though as gev points out, some of the larger bricks had horizontal cross beams. In 1958, Lego applied for a patent for a new design with center posts in the bricks, which allowed for a tighter more stable fit. So, the 1x2 brick without a post is likely a very old lego, and not a specialty piece of some sort. This was certainly not an effort to save plastic, but simply the idea of having a center post hadn't been created yet.

Answer (score -1):

[image: using 3 bricks]
There might be several reasons for leaving out the central post:

- For bricks with a cut-out for wires passing through.
- To be able to attach a 1×1 piece underneath centrally.I
- Also enables a 1mm shorter 1×3 Modulex brick to fit underneath postless 1×2.

  Lego didn't add the posts when the 2×X bricks got their tubes, and there are still no posts with some having end pips.

  Photo: church with light fitted inside, œlephant with bottom 2 of 1×1 bricks central on trunk, a few 1×3 Modulex, 1 with System 1×2 on top.

History, pat. pend. period started with tubes in 2×2 or more in 1958. Pips hidden away on a corner, then bricks got end pips, then pat. pend. obscured till stud pips used.