# White bricks slightly different, real, fake or old?

Tags: clone-brands, colour

These white bricks are slightly different, one of them has the copyright lego on the bottom and the other only has the ID number and some other numbers on the bottom, and the way light enters the brick is totally different (see photos)

They all have the Lego logo on the studs, however.
What is this?
Are they old, fake or just a mold variation?

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 5):

These are almost certainly genuine LEGO elements. I've personally never encountered a clone brand that misused the LEGO trademark on bricks. The issue with the light that you described is well known.

TLG has adjusted the way to color is added to plastic, the color of the pigment used, and the amount of pigment used at various times. This leads bricks produced at different times to have slight color variations and differing levels of translucency. This is a known issue even in current sets. For example, LEGO is aware of an issue with the white tiles the Great Wave (31208) set:

[image: Great Wave 31208]

Here's an example showing obvious color and translucency variation that was present in the tiles that was shared on the LEGO Ambassador Network:

[image: White tile color issues]

Comment: Is there any explanation on why some of my bricks do not have a copyright symbol nor lego on the bottom?
As mentioned they still have the ID numbers and such.

Comment: @StarrySkies64 There have been many minor mold variations over the years. Here are some examples: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/17809/708